# Closest Point Pairs to determine grid resolution

Tags: point, spatial-statistics, scale, grids-graticules, computational-geometry

I'm reading Hengl's (2006) Finding the Right Pixel Size.
In it, among many different suggested approaches, he suggests using a grid resolution where > 95% of the closest point pairs do no fall into the same pixel:

> We can be even more strict and look for a grid resolution where >95%
>   of closest point pairs do not fall into the same pixel. This can be
>   done using some well known point pattern analysis algorithms such as
>   the one described in Boots and Getis (1988) and Rowlingson and Diggle
>   (1993). We first need to derive the probability of finding the first
>   point pair at different distances and for a given data set. We can
>   then select the 5% probability smallest distance.

I am confused about the definition of closest point pairs (plural). In all the definitions I have read, the closest point pair is the ONE pair of points that have the smallest distance between them in a dataset. How could a dataset have multiple closest point pairs (unless they had the exact same distance between them)? Or is something else meant by closest point pairs? Would it be the distance between each point and the point closest to it?

Comment: Point pair distances form a *distribution.*  That's really the only possible sense in which Hengl's proposal can be understood.  "Closest" therefore refers to lower tail of this distribution.  There's still some ambiguity: you could examine the distribution of distances from each point to the nearest one or you could examine the distribution of all point-pair distances.  Your reference likely makes it clear which is meant.